# Qt Creator Error

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Launching debugging for a project and then,

```
Running build steps for project Text_Editor...
Starting: "c:/qt/2010.05/qt/bin/qmake.exe" C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor/Text_Editor.pro -r -spec win32-g++
The process "c:/qt/2010.05/qt/bin/qmake.exe" exited normally.
Starting: "C:/Qt/2010.05/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -w
mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor-build-desktop'

C:/Qt/2010.05/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor-build-desktop'

g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\qt\include\QtCore" -I"..\qt\include\QtGui" -I"..\qt\include" -I"..\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\Text_Editor" -I"." -I"..\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\Text_Editor\main.cpp

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor-build-desktop'

mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor-build-desktop'

g++: ..\Text_Editor\main.cpp: No such file or directory

g++: no input files

mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1

mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2

The process "C:/Qt/2010.05/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" exited with code %2.
Error while building project Text_Editor (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I have no clue on that. I just installed it, created a new project and got that error instantly.

Answer (score 2):

I had pretty much the same problem just now.
Without getting into "why" - I unticked "Shadow build" from project options and my build was succesful. Funny part is - "Shadow build" worked yesterday, and nothing really changed that much in between.

Answer (score 1):

For reason or another it is not able to find your main.cpp (g++: ..\Text_Editor\main.cpp: No such file or directory). Basically that path should be ok if you have shadow build toggled on.

Location where the main.cpp is tried to find is:

C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor/main.cpp

Double check that this is proper location (notice also case sensitivity to be sure)

you can try toggling off the shadow build from project -> check off shadow build. And also you should check that Text_Editor.pro contains properly the main.cpp.

Edit: It might be also wise to create that project outside the Qt binary folder, to some other more logical folder.

Comment: Thanks man, I have added and removed some .cpp and .h files but a copy of .cpp and .h files still placed in .pro file. After deleting the files the application works cool. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your build directory from **C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor-build-desktop** to **C:/Qt/2010.05/Text_Editor**.

To do this just open your project in Qt creator, left click on **Project** on the left pane, then open **build settings** tab and edit **Build directory** input field.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the way I added headers in a .pri.

This works...

```
HEADERS += ../serialportwidget.h
HEADERS += ../serialportworker.h
SOURCES += ../serialportwidget.cpp
SOURCES += ../serialportworker.cpp
```

or this

```
HEADERS += ../serialportwidget.h \
../serialportworker.h
SOURCES += ../serialportwidget.cpp \
../serialportworker.cpp
```

This doesn't...

```
HEADERS += ../serialportwidget.h \ ../serialportworker.h
SOURCES += ../serialportwidget.cpp \ ../serialportworker.cpp
```

Answer (score -1):

Run Qt Creator with "Run as Administrator".

Problem Solved for [debug/main.o] error5

-
Vivin NL

Comment: Apart from the fact that that is pretty unlikely to solve anything (the issue is one of path configuration, not privileges), telling people just to run everything as administrator without explanation or understanding is never good advice.