# Qt Creator Compiling Error at step 'make'

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, makefile

I just started using Qt Creator for creating C++ GUI programs. I just downloaded it and installed it, but the compiling process is throwing me errors. When I try to compile my project (very simple, just a QLabel on the screen...it's my first project) it comes up with the error:

> qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed:
>   C:\Users\andrew\Dropbox\Programming\C++\build-
>   FirstGUIApp-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile 10:04:35:
>   The process
>   "C:\Users\andrew\Dropbox\Programming\C++\build-FirstGUIApp-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile"
>   exited with code -1. Error while building/deploying project
>   FirstGUIApp (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 32bit) When executing step
>   'Make'

I hunted around for an answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769424/qt-creator-error) and [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9234) and a couple other places but I'm just confused about the whole thing. I have a couple of ideas of my own but I don't know how to try my ideas. Here are some of my ideas:

1) MinGW isn't in the path or isn't installed

But, if it isn't in the path, how do I put it in? Where is it? I have Code Blocks installed which has MinGW installed, so could I maybe use it from there?

2) the make file is messed up somehow

Again, what could be wrong and how could I fix it?

3) Qt Creator isn't installed correctly.

Obviously, re-install it, but I want to make sure all other options are tried before, because it took me a very long time to download.

I apologize if I'm sounding noobish or it's a stupid question, but I really am confused with all of this. Please be patient with me and try to explain things well and thoroughly. I'm using Windows 8.1 and downloaded the offline installer. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

---

Here is a screenshot of my Qt, how can I tell if it is the visual studio or minGW version?
[image]

UPDATE

---

Here is my MinGW Folder in CodeBlocks. Is this the folder with the compiler or is it something else?

[image]

Comment: You use the Qt version for MS Visual Studio. You need to download the version for MinGW.

Comment: where can I download that?

Answer (score 3):

For your ideas:
1: if you downloaded from qtproject with binary. then qt and qt creator should be installed under the C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1  then corresponding minGW should be stay in `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\gcc.exe`
this is the directory you need. Remember, QtCreator needs two tools to make sure your project and compile and run, qmake and compiler. 
Qmake is tool help you translate .pro file into makefile, 
compiler (gcc) minGW use gcc to run the makefile, compile your code to binary.

---

where to figure out tools you are using are correct?
---> `qtcreator --> Tools -> Build&Run  -> Kits`
in here You should be able find different kits, of course you maybe have only one.

Select one, Double check the Qt Version and Compiler is the one you wish to use. 
click Manage next to compiler, Every compiler in the Auto-detect should be ok to use.
If you don't see anyone, add one, click Add, MinGW, put `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\gcc.exe` like into path.  ABI should auto-set depends on your environment.

---

Answer to your second question, what's wrong with your makefile, no one knows, you should check your .pro, usually makefile are generated by qmake xx.pro. Double check your .pro file and re-run qmake will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. in tools->options->build&run check if minGW is actually there in the compiler and kit list

   in the project tab (on the left hand side) you can set the environment for the build click the PATH value and add the path to minGW to it (you may need to add a lib and include var so the standard library gets added)
2. re run qmake from the build menu
3. double check you have the correct version it looks like you have the visual studio Qt not the minGW version,

Comment: MinGW is in the compiler kit list. Where can I find minGW to add the path to it? I believe that may be the problem. Would it be in the Qt folders? Also, how can I check it I have the visual studio Qt or the minGW? If it helps I will add a screenshot to the main question.

Comment: minGW should be where you installed it either in the C root or where code blocks is installed, for the Qt versions look where you went to check the kits and look under Qt versions if there is only a msvc (stands for "MicroSoft Visual C") entry then you need to download and add the minGW

Comment: Ill try to add that. Is it a file or a folder? Do you know the name or maybe what file type. Thanks

Comment: you need the folder where the actual compiler is

Comment: I know where the MinGW folder in my CodeBlocks folder is, is that it? Sorry but I really am pretty lost with this all. I'm adding another screenshot to the main question of the MinGW folder I found.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal:(in Linux)
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libqt4-dev

i'm sorry i dont know why this code works,but i have the same problem in linux and this code worked.

Comment: Common practice here at Stack Overflow includes explaining why your code works. Just a code answer does help the OP, but explaining why it works helps the OP wayyyy more

Comment: libqt4-dev is not necessary in Qt5 (tested in 5.5 and 5.7).