# make error when building QT project from source

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, mingw

I have basic hello world source code as hello.cpp for QT Application. I try to build a QT project from that source. My steps:

qmake -project
qmake
make

I have no problem in first 2 steps, it creates debug and release directories (empty), HELLO.pro, Makefile, Makefile.debug, Makefile.release.

When I type make to command line and press enter, I get the following error:

```
make -f Makefile.release
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/HELLO/'
Makefile.Release:62: *** missing seperator. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/HELLO/'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

My Makefile is shown below:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: HELLO
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.3.0)
# Project:  HELLO.pro
# Template: app
# Command: C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile HELLO.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: release
install: release-install
uninstall: release-uninstall
QMAKE         = C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = del
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
COPY          = copy /y
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = del
SYMLINK       = copy /y
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        release \
        debug


release: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release
release-make_first: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release 
release-all: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release all
release-clean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release clean
release-distclean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release distclean
release-install: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install
release-uninstall: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall
debug: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug
debug-make_first: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug 
debug-all: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug all
debug-clean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug clean
debug-distclean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug distclean
debug-install: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug install
debug-uninstall: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug uninstall

Makefile: HELLO.pro C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\spec_pre.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\common\shell-win32.conf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\qconfig.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bluetooth.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bluetooth_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_clucene_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_enginio.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_enginio_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_nfc.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_nfc_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_openglextensions.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_positioning.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_positioning_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmldevtools_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sensors.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sensors_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_serialport.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_serialport_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_websockets.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_websockets_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_winextras.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_winextras_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns_private.pri \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\qt_config.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\spec_post.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\resolve_config.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds_post.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\precompile_header.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\qt.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\resources.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\moc.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\opengl.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\windows.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\testcase_targets.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\exceptions.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf \
        C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\lex.prf \
        HELLO.pro \
        C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/Qt5Gui.prl \
        C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/Qt5Core.prl \
        C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/libEGL.prl \
        C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/libGLESv2.prl
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile HELLO.pro
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\spec_pre.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\common\shell-win32.conf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\qconfig.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bluetooth.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bluetooth_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_clucene_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_enginio.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_enginio_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_nfc.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_nfc_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_openglextensions.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_positioning.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_positioning_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmldevtools_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sensors.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sensors_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_serialport.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_serialport_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_websockets.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_websockets_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_winextras.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_winextras_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns_private.pri:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\qt_config.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\spec_post.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\resolve_config.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds_post.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\precompile_header.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\qt.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\resources.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\moc.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\opengl.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\win32\windows.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\testcase_targets.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\exceptions.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\features\lex.prf:
HELLO.pro:
C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/Qt5Gui.prl:
C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/Qt5Core.prl:
C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/libEGL.prl:
C:/Qt/5.3/msvc2013_64/lib/libGLESv2.prl:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile HELLO.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

make_first: release-make_first debug-make_first FORCE
all: release-all debug-all FORCE
clean: release-clean debug-clean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) HELLO.exp
distclean: release-distclean debug-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile

release-mocclean:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocclean
debug-mocclean:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocclean
mocclean: release-mocclean debug-mocclean

release-mocables:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocables
debug-mocables:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocables
mocables: release-mocables debug-mocables

check: first
FORCE:

$(MAKEFILE).Release: Makefile
$(MAKEFILE).Debug: Makefile
```

Comment: See this link for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355562/qt-creator-compiling-error-at-step-make

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the Qt for MSVC 2013 with mingw. If you want to use mingw, you need to have Qt built for mingw. It can be either from a prebuilt binary install, if one is available, or self-built.

Remember that a particular installation of Qt is for only *one* choice of a compiler and target architecture. The makefile that you have is generated for msvc.

Comment: How can I generate makefile with mingw? It is installed in my PC. Should I install Qt again or is it possible to change my compiler without reinstalling Qt?

Comment: @user3616495 The makefile is generated by qmake, not by mingw. Mingw provides the make tool. You need to install the Qt that is for mingw, not the one for msvc2013 like you did.